# nested context managers in python with list comprehension

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension, contextmanager

Imagine I have two impure functions - f and j.
j generates a list of items in one batch and f generates a list of batches. Both of them have some cleanup to do.

What I need to do is to provide the client code with flattened list of items while making cleanups both for f and j. One way to do that is to use generator with for loop doing cleanup after yield, but I don't like that way because it's not explicit that cleanups exists in that case.

So I found a way to do that by using a wrapper function (called `dumb` in this code)

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from split import chop
from itertools import chain
from functools import wraps

xs = list(chop(3, xrange(9)))


def dumb(manager):
    @wraps(manager)
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        with manager(*args, **kwargs) as something:
            return something
    return g

@dumb
@contextmanager
def j(index):
    print('before j')
    yield xs[index]
    print('after j')

@contextmanager
def f():
    print('before f')
    yield chain.from_iterable(j(i) for i in xrange(len(xs)))

    print('after f')

with f() as ns:
    for x in ns:
        print(x)
```

prints

```
before f
before j
after j
0
1
2
before j
after j
3
4
5
before j
after j
6
7
8
after f
```

EDIT1. It's actually isn't working because it's doing before j and after j before values are actually consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say at this point you've outgrown the `@contextmanager` decorator, and it's time to write your own context manager class.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

xs = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

@contextmanager
def j(index):
    """Same as before. This is a simple context manager."""
    print("j init")
    yield xs[index]
    print("j cleanup")

def _real_f(the_xs):
    """Mostly the same as before. However, any share state created in the 
    init phase should be passed as an argument. As an example I pass in xs."""
    for i in range(len(the_xs)):
        # can now use explicit with statements for j
        with j(i) as it:
            for item in it:
                yield item

class f(object):
    """f is now replaced by a class that can create contexts for the real
    f to work with"""
    def __enter__(self):
        """Init phase. 
        State required by the real f should be passed as an argument (I
        pass in xs)."""
        print("f init")
        return _real_f(xs)

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception, traceback):
        """Clean up phase. 
        Called at end of block. With any details of any exception that
        may have occured in the with block. Return a truthful value to 
        swallow the exception. Can raise your own exception if there is a 
        problem in the clean up phase."""
        print("f clean up")

with f() as it:
    for item in it:
        print(item)
```

Comment: Okay, this is working, is there any chance to solve this with one line ```with j(i) as it: for item in it: yield item```?

Comment: Not sure how that ties in with your requirement for explicit cleanup.